# Compile Error: /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libmysqlclient.a: No such file or directory

Tags: linux

```
make all
rm -rf build/gov/fcc/tvstudy; \
javac -sourcepath src -encoding UTF8 -classpath build -d build src/gov/fcc/tvstudy/AppManager.java; \
jar cmf Manifest.txt tvstudy.jar -C build gov/fcc/tvstudy
Note: Some input files use unchecked or unsafe operations.
Note: Recompile with -Xlint:unchecked for details.
gcc -D__BUILD_LINUX -Wall -I/usr/include/mysql -o build/tvstudy.o -c src/tvstudy.c
gcc -D__BUILD_LINUX -Wall -I/usr/include/mysql -o build/study.o -c src/study.c
gcc -D__BUILD_LINUX -Wall -I/usr/include/mysql -o build/parameter.o -c src/parameter.c
gcc -D__BUILD_LINUX -Wall -I/usr/include/mysql -o build/source.o -c src/source.c
gcc -D__BUILD_LINUX -Wall -I/usr/include/mysql -o build/report.o -c src/report.c
gcc -D__BUILD_LINUX -Wall -I/usr/include/mysql -o build/cell.o -c src/cell.c
gcc -D__BUILD_LINUX -Wall -I/usr/include/mysql -o build/cache.o -c src/cache.c
gcc -D__BUILD_LINUX -Wall -I/usr/include/mysql -o build/pattern.o -c src/pattern.c
gcc -D__BUILD_LINUX -Wall -I/usr/include/mysql -o build/fcc_curve.o -c src/fcc_curve.c
src/fcc_curve.c: In function ‘fcc_itplbv’:
src/fcc_curve.c:626:24: warning: variable ‘lyp1’ set but not used [-Wunused-but-set-variable]
  int lxm1, lxp1, lym1, lyp1, ixpv, iypv, k, ix, iy, imn, imx, jx, jy, jx1, jy1;
                        ^
src/fcc_curve.c:626:12: warning: variable ‘lxp1’ set but not used [-Wunused-but-set-variable]
  int lxm1, lxp1, lym1, lyp1, ixpv, iypv, k, ix, iy, imn, imx, jx, jy, jx1, jy1;
            ^
gcc -D__BUILD_LINUX -Wall -I/usr/include/mysql -o build/longley_rice.o -c src/longley_rice.c
gfortran -o build/itsitm.o -c src/itsitm.f
gcc -D__BUILD_LINUX -Wall -I/usr/include/mysql -o build/terrain.o -c src/terrain.c
gcc -D__BUILD_LINUX -Wall -I/usr/include/mysql -o build/landcover.o -c src/landcover.c
gcc -D__BUILD_LINUX -Wall -I/usr/include/mysql -o build/map.o -c src/map.c
gcc -D__BUILD_LINUX -Wall -I/usr/include/mysql -o build/coordinates.o -c src/coordinates.c
gcc -D__BUILD_LINUX -Wall -I/usr/include/mysql -o build/memory.o -c src/memory.c
gcc -D__BUILD_LINUX -Wall -I/usr/include/mysql -o build/log.o -c src/log.c
gcc -Wall -I/usr/include/mysql -o tvstudy build/tvstudy.o build/study.o build/parameter.o build/source.o build/report.o build/cell.o build/cache.o build/pattern.o build/fcc_curve.o build/longley_rice.o build/itsitm.o build/terrain.o build/landcover.o build/map.o build/coordinates.o build/memory.o build/log.o /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libmysqlclient.a -lpthread -lm -ldl -lz
gcc: error: /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libmysqlclient.a: No such file or directory
make: *** [tvstudy] Error 1
```

I am trying to install the FCC's TVStudy Software and got the following message.

Running Manjaro 0.8.6 64-Bit

Comment: OS? 
SOLUTION: Install mysql-devel package

Answer (score 0):

Is that file found in the location stated by gcc? If not then use your package manager to find that specific library and install it.

```
pacman -Ss libmysqlclient
```